# Dynamic key value in find statement Mongodb and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wonder why does I can't get result on Find query with dynamic key object as parameter.

My goal is to make searching Api with dynamic key and value parameter.

as I always get an empty result with this :

```
module.exports = function (app, db) {

      app.post('/getUser/', function(request, response){

      /* Preparing dynamic params */
      var param = {
         request.body.key : /request.body.value/
      };

      db.collection('user').find(param).toArray(function(err, result){

         console.log(result);
      })
   })

}
```

But I can get proper result with "hard coded" parameter like this :

module.exports = function (app, db) {

```
      app.post('/getUser/', function(request, response){

      db.collection('user').find({ name : /John/ }).toArray(function(err, result){

         console.log(result);
      })
   })

}
```

Any answer will be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: It should be `var param = {
         [request.body.key] : new RegExp(request.body.value)
      }`

Comment: Please use `console.log()` to check what value you are getting.

Comment: @RaR, Thankss it's working!, any explaination??

Comment: We are using ES2015's computed keys here. Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer. And for value, it took `request.body.value` as raw string. We used `RegExp` constructor for dynamic values